# Risk-like (area-based) maps and HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a Risk-like world map which is divided into regions of custom shape.

How does one enable the user to select an individual region using HTML5/JavaScript? I assume Canvas2D is the first step, but then what?

[image: DominateGame]

Comment: raphaeljs has a demo that uses a svg to make a clickable map http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are gazillions of great libraries. To name a few:

- http://d3js.org/
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://paperjs.org/
- http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/
- http://threejs.org/

Specific examples:

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590
- http://raphaeljs.com/world/
- http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map tag that you then add to your img tag. In your map tag, you define different areas where the user can click. Then, you can define javascript functions to be call on the mousedown event of each area.

I don't like explanation, I prefer examples! So here a link I just found that describe this technique better :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_image_map.htm

And by the way, you don't need to manually create the areas. There are a tons of WYSIWYG tools out there that will create it for you!

Comment: Not generally a wrong answer, but image maps don't suit my situation well.

Comment: No offense, but you provided very little information in your question, so this answer is perfectly ok.

Comment: Well, I don't think that my answer is wrong because it fits HTML/JavaScript. But using a library is a really good practice!